# PHP blocking request to remote webservices with guzzle

Tags: php, curl, laravel-4, nonblocking, guzzle

i'm trying to execute a request to a web service to download large files to my server. My web application is in laravel 4 and i'm using guzzle to make the request.

The problem is, after starting the file download from the remote service, i can't execute any request to my app until the download response is complete.

Here is a example of my code:

```
    public function download($id, $url, $filename)
    {
        // some data for request

        $request = $httpClient->get($downloadFileUrl, array(
               'future' => true, 
               'cookies' => true, 
               'save_to' => $filename
               )
         );

         return $cookieRequest;
     }
```

In the past i use exec to start curl or wget scripts to downlaod the files to the server. But i would like to have more control over the requests and responses.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [work queues](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues) to run the download in the background:

```
Queue::push(function($job)
{
    $request = $httpClient->get($downloadFileUrl, array(
        'future' => true, 
        'cookies' => true, 
        'save_to' => $filename
    ));

    $job->delete();
});
```

Here's a good article on how to [Setup Laravel with Beanstalkd](http://fideloper.com/ubuntu-beanstalkd-and-laravel4), but you could also use others like IronMQ, Amazon SQS, Redis.